# Sqlite The supported APIs test detected the following errors

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I finished my app for Windows Phone 8.1. I have used sqlite database. When I run WACK I get this error. Someone told me to try uninstalling the kb 2976978 update, but I don't have any update with this name.

How can I resolve this problem?

The supported APIs test detected the following errors:

```
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_bind_blob. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_bind_double. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_bind_int. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_bind_int64. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_bind_null. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_bind_parameter_index. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_bind_text16. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_busy_timeout. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_changes. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_close. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_blob. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_bytes. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_count. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_double. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_int. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_int64. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_name. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_text16. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_column_type. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_errmsg. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_extended_errcode. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_finalize. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_last_insert_rowid. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_mprintf. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_open. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_open_v2. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_prepare16_v2. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_reset. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_step. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=sqlite3_temp_directory. Module=sqlite3.dll. File=Sqlite.dll.
```

Comment: What settings did you build you app package with?

Comment: On release mode & ARM

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `sqlite3.dll` in your app's package? The WACK works on a "deny by default" basis, so if you use an API that isn't either (a) in your package or (b) on the allow-list, it is denied. If `sqlite3.dll` isn't in your app package, WACK assumes it is an OS binary and since it isn't on the allow list, you get an error.